# network traffic of application

Tags: iphone, ios4, network-programming

Is it possible to measure the network traffic of applications running in iphone ?
can anyone suggest me the road map or example kind of thing please ?

Using proxy is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can use the Paros proxy which was built for web application security assessments.  Tutorial can be found here: [Sniff Your iPhone's Network Traffic](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/06/sniff-your-iphones-network-traffic/).

Comment: i want to monitor network traffic of iphone within iphone only